# How to print color box on the console in python?

Tags: python, unicode, colors, console

I want to plot HeatMap on the console. For that purpose I want to plot small boxex of different colors i.e | | this size. I got different color Unicode symbols to plot HeatMap on the console but they are not working good. whenever I'm printing color on the 1st line it gets reflected on the 2nd line also.

**I have following Unicode's-**

```
'\033[0;37;40m  '
'\033[0;37;46m  '
'\033[0;37;44m  '
'\033[0;37;45m  '
'\033[0;37;42m  '
'\033[48;5;226m  '
'\033[48;5;214m  '
'\033[48;5;202m  '
'\033[48;5;196m  '
'\033[0;37;41m  '
```

**program-code-**

```
print('\033[0;37;40m  ')
print 'hello'
```

Whenever I'm trying to print some text between color code It get fetched. Anyone have any Idea about How I can plot a different colors of empty box i.e. only color not text on the python console in a efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

That's not "unicode", they're called [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

For your purpose, you can print a space character with a modified background color, and don't forget to set the colors back to normal afterwards (with `\033[0m`):

```
print('\033[;41m  ')
print('\033[0mhello')
```

A list of colors can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). 42 would be green, 43 would be yellow, etc.